# Rspec testing nested destroy action for follows model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, nested-attributes

I have researched and seen a similar question ([Rspec: Testing nested destroy action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29087023/rspec-testing-nested-destroy-action)) but was unable to get the solution to work for me. In the app I am working on, we have an Articles model and users can Follow Articles.

I have used the acts_as_follower gem to implement this, so Article model has a 'followers' method that returns and array of users following that article.

Here is the relevant code:

follows_controller

```
class FollowsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    current_user.follow(@article)
    redirect_to @article
  end

  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])    
    current_user.stop_following(@article)
    redirect_to @article
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
    get '/articles/:id/history', to: 'articles#history', as: :articles_history
  post '/articles/:id/undo', to: 'articles#undo', as: :undo
  resources :articles do
    resources :follows, :only => [:create, :destroy]
  end
```

schema.rb

```
create_table "follows", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "followable_id",                   null: false
    t.string   "followable_type",                 null: false
    t.integer  "follower_id",                     null: false
    t.string   "follower_type",                   null: false
    t.boolean  "blocked",         default: false, null: false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

spec/controllers/follows_controller_spec.rb updated per @Peter's comment below

```
  describe '#DELETE destroy' do
it 'deletes a follow' do
  @article = FactoryGirl.create(:article)
  follow = FactoryGirl.create(:follow, followable_id: @article.id)
  # Also, test if the action really deletes a comment.
  expect{delete :destroy, id: follow.id, article_id: @article.id}.
  to change{@article.followers.count}.by(-1)
end
```

end

rake routes:

```
article_follows POST   /articles/:article_id/follows(.:format)          follows#create
article_follow DELETE /articles/:article_id/follows/:id(.:format)      follows#destroy
```

Here is the error I get on running the test:

Failures:

```
1) FollowsController#DELETE destroy deletes a follow
     Failure/Error: expect{delete :destroy, id: follow.id, followable_id: @article.id}.
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"follows", :followable_id=>"2", :id=>"2"}
```

Adding Factory and new error based on @PeterAlfvin's suggestion below:

here is my factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :follow do |f|
    f.follower_id 1
    f.followable_id 1
    f.followable_type "Article"
    f.follower_type "User"
  end
end
```

and here is the current error:

```
  1) FollowsController#DELETE destroy deletes a follow
     Failure/Error: expect{delete :destroy, id: follow.id, article_id: @article.id}.
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `stop_following' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/controllers/follows_controller.rb:10:in `destroy'
     # ./.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
     # ./.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
     # ./.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
     # ./.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
     # ./.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
     # ./.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
     # ./.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
     # ./.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
     # ./.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
     # ./.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
     # ./.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
     # ./.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
     # ./.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
     # ./.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
     # ./.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
     # ./.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
     # ./.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
     # ./.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
     # ./.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
     # ./.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
     # ./.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/searchkick-0.8.7/lib/searchkick/logging.rb:107:in `process_action'
     # ./.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
     # ./.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
     # ./.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
     # ./.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:632:in `process'
     # ./.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:65:in `process'
     # ./.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb:19:in `block in process'
     # ./.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb:72:in `catch'
     # ./.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb:72:in `_catch_warden'
     # ./.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb:19:in `process'
     # ./.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:532:in `delete'
     # ./spec/controllers/follows_controller_spec.rb:22:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/controllers/follows_controller_spec.rb:22:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/spec_helper.rb:57:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.3.0/lib/database_cleaner/generic/base.rb:15:in `cleaning'
     # ./.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.3.0/lib/database_cleaner/base.rb:92:in `cleaning'
     # ./.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.3.0/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in cleaning'
     # ./.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.3.0/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:87:in `call'
     # ./.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.3.0/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:87:in `cleaning'
     # ./spec/spec_helper.rb:56:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: where do you define `delete_request` ?

Comment: I copied and pasted a previous error by mistake.  corrected above.

Comment: try replacing `followable_id` with `article_id`

Comment: changed to this: describe '#DELETE destroy' do
    it 'deletes a follow' do
      @article = FactoryGirl.create(:article)
      follow = FactoryGirl.create(:follow, article_id: @article.id)
      # Also, test if the action really deletes a comment.
      expect{delete :destroy, id: follow.id, article_id: @article.id}.
      to change{@article.followers.count}.by(-1)
    end
  end  get error:  NoMethodError:
       undefined method `article_id=' for #<Follow:

Comment: edited the question to include the schema for Follows table.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin not sure that the routing question has been resolved.  There is no article_id method to the Follow model, which is why I edited the question to include the schema. substituting article_id does just returns a no method error.

Comment: Indeed, you're right. I removed my comment and posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the routing error was indeed due to specifying `followable_id` rather than `article_id` as implied by the comment you received. The subsequent no method error, however, was due to making that change in the factory call as well. The following is what you should try:

```
describe '#DELETE destroy' do
  it 'deletes a follow' do
    @article = FactoryGirl.create(:article)
    follow = FactoryGirl.create(:follow, followable_id: @article.id)
    # Test if the action really deletes a follow.
    expect{delete :destroy, id: follow.id, article_id: @article.id}.
    to change{@article.followers.count}.by(-1)
  end
end
```

Comment: Peter,  thanks for this.  I have implemented but now get an error which I think is suggesting that i haven't created a valid article object: undefined method `stop_following' for nil:NilClass. stop_following is a method provided by the gem.

Comment: No, `stop_following` is being called on `current_user`, so you apparently are not logged in.