# How to pass ID in delete :destroy in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

It is super simple, yet I can't figure out  how to make the test pass.

I have a `friendships` controller that I wanted to test (I am building Rails app similar to [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association?autoplay=true)). It works on localhost. This is the test that I created. `POST #create` passed.

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe FriendshipsController, type: :controller do
  login_user

  before :each do
    @friend1 = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  end

  describe "POST #Create" do
    it "adds new friend" do
      expect {
        post :create, params: { friend_id: @friend1.id}
      }.to change(Friendship, :count).by(1)
    end
  end

  describe "DELETE #destroy" do
    it "removes a friend =(" do
      expect {
        delete :destroy, id: @friend1.id
      }.to change(Friendship, :count).by(1)
    end
  end

end
```

This is the actual controller:

```
class FriendshipsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @friendship = current_user.friendships.build(friend_id: params[:friend_id])
    if @friendship.save
      flash[:notice] = "New friend added!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash[:error] = "Error adding friend"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @friendship = current_user.friendships.find(params[:id])
    @friendship.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Remove friendship"
    redirect_to current_user
  end
end
```

I also made sure that `routes.rb` have Friendships: `resources :friendships`

The problem I am having is to pass the ID.I can't figure out how to pass the `id` params. I think it has something to do with my factory...?

```
  1) FriendshipsController DELETE #destroy removes a friend =(
     Failure/Error: @friendship = current_user.friendships.find(params[:id])

     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find Friendship with 'id'=159 [WHERE "friendships"."user_id" = $1]
```

I search for other SO `destroy` related posts, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19810635/how-can-this-destroy-action-be-tested-with-rspec), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29087023/rspec-testing-nested-destroy-action), but they are different case from mine.

How can I pass down ID params for my destroy action?

EDIT: ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23793597/how-to-access-devise-current-user-in-a-rspec-feature-test))

```
module ControllerMacros
  def login_user
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      #user.confirm! # or set a confirmed_at inside the factory. Only necessary if you are using the "confirmable" module
      sign_in user
    end
  end
end
```

As suggested by answer below, I did:

```
describe "DELETE #destroy" do
    it "removes a friend =(" do
      friendship = user.friendships.create!(friend_id: @friend1.id)
      expect {
        delete :destroy, id: friendship.id
      }.to change(Friendship, :count).by(1)
    end
  end
```

But it is now returning this error:

```
FriendshipsController DELETE #destroy removes a friend =(
     Failure/Error: friendship = user.friendships.create!(friend_id: @friend1.id)

     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `user' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::FriendshipsController::DELETEDestroy:0x007fee1ce68c70>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're looking for the friendship, not the user in the controller, you need to create the friendship first. Before that you also need to know the user to be logged in. Try sending that first:

```
module ControllerMacros
  def login_user(user)
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      user ||= FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      sign_in user
    end
  end
end
```

Now the test would look something like this:

```
let(:current_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
login_user(current_user)

describe "DELETE #destroy" do
  it "removes a friend =(" do
    friendship = current_user.friendships.create!(friend_id: @friend1.id)
    expect {
      delete :destroy, id: friendship.id
    }.to change(Friendship, :count).by(1)
  end
end
```

You should be good to go now.

Comment: Thanks, @Babar! I made progress, but I am still having trouble. `undefined local variable or method user`. I edited my answer to include what's inside `login_user` and my new DELETE test. Do you know what I did wrong?